# Function of parallel().map().toArray()

Tags: java, arrays, function

I came across the function parallel().map().toArray() in a java code written for cross product computation of vectors. Wanted to know what does this function do?

Comment: Those are actually 3 distinct _methods_, probably those in the Stream API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

Answer (score 0):

It's part of Java 8 streams methods. Things you mentioned

pararell() - executes using multiple cores

map() - performs some mapping ( for example object.getMyValue() ) and transforms it

toArray() - puts result of parallel into array

Read more here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/